# Dietary Concern: Top Round Steak

Tags: diet, protein

I train a lot: 5 days a week 30-60 minutes of cardio, 4-5 days a week weight lifting (primarily strength training, lots of dead lifts and squats), 3-4 days a week rock climbing and 2 days a week yoga. Recently, I decided to give up all supplements, including protein shakes, and have opted to get all my nutrition from more traditional sources (eg anything that doesn't come in a powder or a pill). So to meet my protein needs, I have started eating approximately 1 lb of top round steak a day. My question is this: given my current regiment, should I be concerned about the negative side effects of consuming so much red meat?

Comment: I have started back up on RTD 51's, so I sorta failed to kick the liquid protein, however I am still consuming .75 lbs of meat a day, and so far so good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing anything specific about your health condition and such, I would suspect the worst that could happen is you'd end up constipated if you're not getting a good amount of fibre with your steak as well. Depending on how recently you did the switch, it might also be an idea to ease yourself into it, so phase out your supplement usage over 1-2 weeks and increase eating steak, chicken, eggs and the like over the same period. I'm also a fan of traditional sources but the abrupt change might (again, depending on your specific situation) be a bit more of a shock than specifically how much you're eating.

Comment: +1 Easing into a new diet and not focusing on red meat (vs. white meat, etc.)

Comment: I have eased into it, and have no health conditions and eat lots of cereal. Eggs every morning, and the occasional chicken (however, I kind of hate chicken)

Comment: Not a huge fan of it either, maybe turkey is more your taste?

Comment: God, I hate turkey even more.

Comment: Fowl is foul eh? Fish?

Comment: I like my sushi